# GWT:how to get selected radio button's value

Tags: gwt

I am create dynamic number of radio buttons in my GWT

```
      public void createTestList(ArrayList<Test> result){
    for(int i =0 ; i<result.size();i++){
                    int id = result.get(i).getTestId();
        RadioButton rd = new RadioButton("group", result.get(i).getTestType());
        verticalPanel.add(rd);
    }
```

where Test is my Entity class ..

I am getting 4 different types of radio buttons in my view , Now if i select any one of the radio button, first I need to get the id of the selected Radio button , how can this be possible ?

secondly How will i check that which one of the multiple radio button is selected ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to check public java.lang.Boolean getValue() on each radio button whether it is checked or not.

Comment: thanks , but the radio buttons are creating dynamically at the run time , also there could be different radio buttons values every time , as they are coming from DB

Comment: True, you can have references of rb instances in an array and iterate through when you want to check which one is selected.

Comment: Thanks , its working , u have any idea of my First Question, Basically the selected item is a "type" of testClass , but there's testId there as well , is there a way i can get the test ID of that selected radio button ,like some way by which I can save the testId at the time of creating radiobutton,  like    { RadioButton rd = new RadioButton("group", result.get(i).getTestType());   } as i get the the type here , in the same way can i store a testId to this radio button ?thanks

Comment: <span class="gwt-RadioButton"><input tabindex="0" id="gwt-uid-3" value="on" name="group" type="radio"><label for="gwt-uid-3">Security</label></span>  ::  this is my selectedRsdioButton ,u see gwt-uid-3 , I want this "3" in my method , how can we get this value out? thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `ensureDebugId()`?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to add click handler and update selected radio button variable:

```
choiceItemKind = new VerticalPanel();
ArrayList<String> kinds = new ArrayList<String>();
kinds.add(...);
kinds.add(...);

choiceItemKind.clear();

ClickHandler choiceClickHandler = new ClickHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        addItemKindSelectedLabel = ((RadioButton) event.getSource()).getText();
    }
};

for (String label : kinds)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton("kind", label);
    //radioButton.setTitle("Tooltyp");
    if (label.equals(addItemKindSelectedLabel))
        radioButton.setValue(true);
    radioButton.addClickHandler(choiceClickHandler);
    choiceItemKind.add(radioButton);
}
...
addItemKindSelectedLabel = "";
...
if (!addItemKindSelectedLabel.isEmpty())
    ...;
```

upd: set selected radiobutton without rebuild:

```
for (int i = 0; i < choiceItemKind.getWidgetCount(); i++)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) choiceItemKind.getWidget(i);
    radioButton.setValue(radioButton.getText().equals(addItemKindSelectedLabel));
}
```